# Upgrade android 4.2.2 to 4.4 (MHTMID-B718DC8 DualCore-A23)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, 4.2-jelly-bean, tablet

I was trying to look up some way on upgrading this device I have to a later version (kitkat) so I'd have more functionality with this tab. I know it is a bit of a low end device but is highly able to be overclocked. The build version is MHTMID-B718DC8_20140716 and android 4.2.2. Kernel Version 3.4.39 swtest@swtest-desktop #37. I also was looking for a custom recovery as cwm doesn't support my device. I have rooted the device using Kingo Root. Hopefully its possible. Its a Mikona brand tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of custom Android ROMs out there, you need to find one that was made for your specific device. [XDA-developpers](https://www.xda-developers.com/) and [FreakTab](http://freaktab.com/) are good places to look. Flashing requires a few utilities, but it is a fairly straight-forward process. Whomever made a custom ROM for your device would tell you the specific flashing procedure and utilities for your tablet.

Your first step is to find a custom ROM that was made for your specific tablet. I still run custom KitKat ROMs on a couple of old phones.